# Accessing JS array object using string

Tags: javascript, key-value

```
var arr ={count:12,total:110};
console.log(arr.count,'',arr.total)   //12 110
```

but how to use like this

```
var c='count';
console.log(arr.c) //it's not similar to arr.count is there is any way to use this
```

How to access the array object by referring to the string?

Comment: Use bracket notation. `console.log(arr[c]) `

Comment: Just a note: `arr` is not an array, it's an object.

Answer (score 1):

```
var c='count';
console.log(arr[c])
```

You can access the key/properties using bracket notation

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr ={count:12,total:110};
var c='count';

console.log(arr[c],'',arr.total)   //12 110
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var c = arr['count'];
```